# error on compass watch

Tags: ruby, rubygems, compass-sass

Below is the error that I get on executing `compass watch` -

```
LoadError on line ["36"] of /home/murtaza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: cannot load such file -- ceaser-easing
```

How do I remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was due to plugins that had to be installed.

Adding the content as requested -

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

require "ceaser-easing"
require "grid-coordinates"
require "compass_twitter_bootstrap"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "templ/sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false

preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Could you please explain what caused the problem and how you solved it? I would much appreciate it! Cheers!

Comment: I opened its config file, and there I could see it was loading some plugins. Then installed those plugins. See your error trace for any hints.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the contents of your compass.rb file in the question?

Comment: Added, and check the require statements.

Comment: Cheers! Which plugin was causing it then? In my case I have exactly the same error, but really the only gem I am trying to use is 'ceaser-easing'. I am trying to figure out if there is no other gems, what is causing it.